# Load external data in html-page with d3.v5/JavaScript to avoid cross-site-scripting

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to load external data in my html-page. I'm executing an external script, using a  inside . If the data is inside the html-page the data is processing correctly. If the data is in my external dataset.js, I got Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…1630896e-15,-90LNaN,NaNZ".

html

```
<script src="d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="dataset-pie.js"></script>
    
// Create dummy data
    //var dataset = [
    //    { name: 'Success', count: 546 },
    //    { name: 'Error', count: 155 }
    //    ];
    
    var total=0;
    
    dataset.forEach(function(d){
            total+= d.count;
        });
```

dataset.js

```
    dataset=[
    {
    "name": "Success", 
    "count": 546
    },
    {
    "name": "Error",
    "count": 155
    },
    ]
```

Comment: I just want adding that I can`t use a code like "var loadData = function() {
        d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(data) {..." because of the above metioned risks.

Comment: What risks do you mean? It seems you try to load the data incorrectly. you should process the data inside the d3.csv()... The only reason not to use fetch like d3.csv(), etc... is if you don't have access to a web server. Then you have to put your data in the .js section or in a HTML node - but this is more of a hack...

Comment: Correct. Due to our security-police I didn't grant access to the internet or any other webserver, instead the one I use for our internal visualization. It ist only permitted loading local stored data. For my MVP I used the data inside the *.html-File. But for a daily actualisation of the data, I need to store the raw data outside of the html.file.